# Postgresql - selecting from one partition is much slower then selecting from another

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE public."ToProcessVideoIds" (
"Id" text NOT NULL,
"IsProcessed" bool NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "PK_ToProcessVideoIdsPartitioned" PRIMARY KEY ("Id", "IsProcessed")
)
PARTITION BY LIST ("IsProcessed");
```

with two partitions by a boolean field `IsProcessed`.

```
CREATE TABLE public."ToProcessVideoIds_processed" PARTITION OF public.ToProcessVideoIds 
FOR VALUES IN (true);


CREATE TABLE public."ToProcessVideoIds_unprocessed" PARTITION OF 
public.ToProcessVideoIds FOR VALUES IN (false);
```

when I filter by `IsProcessed` (or when I select directly from partition) it's much faster for `processed` partition 0.06ms vs 27ms

```
explain (ANALYZE, TIMING, COSTS, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)    select "Id" from "ToProcessVideoIds_unprocessed" limit 50;
Limit  (cost=0.00..0.81 rows=50 width=12) (actual time=27.350..27.358 rows=50 loops=1)
  Output: "Id"
  Buffers: shared hit=7265
  ->  Seq Scan on public."ToProcessVideoIds_unprocessed"  (cost=0.00..317346.99 rows=19697899 width=12) (actual time=27.349..27.353 rows=50 loops=1)
        Output: "Id"
        Buffers: shared hit=7265
Planning Time: 0.044 ms
Execution Time: 27.373 ms
```

_

```
explain (ANALYZE, TIMING, COSTS, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)    select "Id" from "ToProcessVideoIds_processed" limit 50;
Limit  (cost=0.00..0.77 rows=50 width=12) (actual time=0.040..0.049 rows=50 loops=1)
  Output: "Id"
  Buffers: shared hit=1
  ->  Seq Scan on public."ToProcessVideoIds_processed"  (cost=0.00..294045.98 rows=19038398 width=12) (actual time=0.040..0.044 rows=50 loops=1)
        Output: "Id"
        Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.030 ms
Execution Time: 0.059 ms
```

Did I configure something incorrectly? Is there a way to select from _unrpocessed partition with the same performance?

Records are updated all the time (unprocessed become processed) - could this affect anything?

There is roughly the same amount of data in both partitions.

Answer (score 1):

> Records are updated all the time (unprocessed become processed) -
> could this affect anything?

this was good clue. vacuum helped. any performance advises here? Should I just define a more aggressive vacuum setting?

Comment: More aggressive vacuuming could help.  But really, what is the point of seeing 50 completely arbitrary records?  That is the kind of thing you do when exploring a dataset you have never seen before.  If there is no reason to run a query more than once every decade, then it doesn't matter if it is slightly slow.

Comment: @jjanes

It's just a backgournd worker process. It that takes 50 unprocessed records, processes them and marks as processed

Autovacum is never called, for some reason. For now I launch vacum manually couple times a day,  can't figure out why autovacuum doesn't work

Comment: Usually you would want some kind of order clause, to enforce that records are processed in roughly the order they arrived or something.  Work queues are hard to optimize in a relational database, there are dedicated queuing systems you might want to look into.  Or if you just selected 500 at a time rather than 50, it would take only slightly more time to run but would need to run only 1/10 as often.

Comment: The default auto vac only kicks in once 20% of a table has turned over.  But 20% of a large table is a lot, especially if all of the turn over is concentrated in one part of the table, and that is the same part that sees all the other activity as well.